# Cytoscape (desktop application): select all neighbour nodes connected by edge with a given attribute

Tags: cytoscape

I have a node N and i need to get all of it's first neighbours (pretty much like Select -> Select first neighbours), however, i need only such neighbours that are connected by a specific edge type (edge with specific attribute).

In Cypher, it would look like this (in a case of the N is Tom Hanks and the edge type is ACTED_IN):

```
MATCH (n:Person)-[r:ACTED_IN]->(n2) WHERE n.name = "Tom Hanks"   return n, r, n2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as the task:

1) select node N you want to work with,

2) click Filter in side menu, then Chain card,

3) Set the following chain:

- Start with: *Current situation*
- add *Node adjacency Transformer*

  - Take nodes and *add* and *adjacent nodes and edges*, where the *adjacent edges* match the filter:
    *Edge: edge_type* and *contains* wanted type *ACTED_IN*.

Works fine.